# Running NServiceBusHost.exe from Powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-services, nservicebus

Hi I have a powershell script to stop a service from the cluster manager, uninstall the service, reinstall the service, and start the service from the cluster manager.  NServiceBus.Host.exe is used to uninstall and reinstall the service.  I am running into issues with the install.  The service is getting successfully installed but the service is always an Automatic startup type even when I send in "/startManually" as a parameter.  Secondly, on the install, I get a Login failed for user sql error stating that the userName is the local machine name even though I specify the username and password for the service to use.  Below is  my line of code to install the service.  Any help would be a blessing.

```
& "NServiceBus.Host.exe" ("/install", "/startManually", "/serviceName:$ServiceName", "/displayName:$ServiceName", "/username:$ServiceUserName", "/password:$ServicePassword") > tmp.txt
```

Comment: We're investigating the /startManually (will report back here). Regarding the connection to the DB: We run the schemaupdates as the user that runs the install since the "service" user that you specify probably wouldn't have rights to update/create tables in production.

Comment: Thanks for posting this, this will be handled in NSErviceBus version 3.4. There is a pending issue for that on NServiceBus GitHub: [link](https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/issues/700)

Comment: So I need to run the powershell script as a user that has rights on both the machine it is installing on as well as rights to the database it is pointing to?

Comment: Is there anything we can put in our config to prevent the schemaupdates from happening?

Comment: Andreas, any updates on Lizzard question. I have a scenario where - client uses windows auth for sql - I am deploying from teamcity (builduser) - which doesn't have access to the Database only the service account has access to it. Is there a way to either
a) tell NSB to create tables for sagas etc or table for subscription on the first start instead of install
b) or - run installer with runas option - I tried Start-Process on psremoting with credentials but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

I generally recommend using the `Start-Process` cmdlet to launch processes from PowerShell. This makes the whole process (no pun intended) of launching processes much easier to troubleshoot.

You can build your command line arguments into a variable, and pass that resulting variable into the `-ArgumentList` parameter.

```
$Arguments = '/install /startManually /serviceName:{0} /displayName:{0} /username:{1} /password:{2}' -f $ServiceName, $ServiceUserName, $ServicePassword)
$nServiceBus = Resolve-Path -Path nServiceBus.Host.exe;

Write-Host -Object ('Argument string is: {0}' -f $Arguments);
Write-Host -Object ('Path to nServiceBus.Host.exe is: {0}' -f $nServiceBus);
Start-Process -Wait -NoNewWindow -FilePath $nServiceBus -ArgumentList $Arguments -RedirectStandardOutput tmp.txt;
```

Hope this helps.